# Use regex to match certain number of lines that follow the line containing the occurrence of a specific string

Tags: regex, grep, adobe-indesign

I am working in InDesign, formatting large quantities of text. Here is a sample of the text.

> NEW! Certificate in Office Operations (3 parts)
>   Office Operations
>   Cyber Security for Managers
>   Embracing Sustainability in the Workplace
>   Intro to 3D Printing
>   Intro to Maker Tech: The New Shop Class

I need to be able to match the three lines that follow a line containing the string "(3 parts)".

My thought would be to try a positive look-behind like this:

```
(?<=\(3 parts\)$)^.*$
```

but it doesn't match anything.

Comment: The dot `.` does not match newline characters, that is why. Additionally, are there really empty lines between the text?

Comment: Are you using `grep` in Unix?

Comment: no there aren't empty lines in between the text. I just couldnt get the blockquote feature to work. :s

Comment: using grep in the find/change tool of Adobe Indesign.

Comment: @jseymour186, if you leave two or more spaces at the end of a line, the line break is preserved.  I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

The lookbehind part is correct, but the use of the symbols `^` (Begin Paragraph) and `$` (End Paragraph) are restricted to matching the *position* only – not the actual 'Hard return' characters. That is the reason your expression fails: by default, the `.` "match all" character does *not* match returns. So that makes the first test `(?<=\(3 parts\)$)^.` fail: neither the `$` in the lookbehind nor the `^` consumed the return, and the following `.` does not match it either, per this default rule.

It is possible to put GREP into Single Line mode – a funny description that may put you on the wrong foot. From the perspective of GREP, it allows `.` to match a return as well; and so an entire running text, hard returns and all, can be considered a "single (long) line". The code for that is `(?s)`, and is typically put at the very front of your expression.

That in itself is not enough to make it work, because

```
(?s)(?<=\(3 parts\)$)^.
```

still expects a return *between* the `$` and `^` (otherwise either one would be wrong!). Anyway, it's not a good way to match a certain number of paragraphs. The adjusted expression

```
(?s)(?<=\(3 parts\)$).^.*
```

works correctly in consuming the hard returns, but selects everything up to the end as well.

I propose a much simpler approach: if you want to grab a certain number of hard returns, just include them right away in your expression – their GREP code is `\r`.

That leads to the following:

```
(?<=\(3 parts\)\r)(.*\r){3}
```

where the lookbehind is what you already got, plus a return to end that particular line (and it's in the lookbehind because you don't want to grab that return as well), followed by three repetitions of a sequence to grab an entire line, `.*\r`.

Comment: The [InDesign docs](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/find-change.html#metacharacters_for_searching) list `\r` as "End of Paragraph" and `\n` as "Forced Line Break".  Based on that description, I suspect `\n` is what's wanted here.

Comment: @AlanMoore: Adobe incorporated boost's GREP wholesale (they also inserted a few functions themself, which makes that otherwise very reliable code break at some points...), and explaining it is not their strongest point. The usual way to write such a list is with regular returns; but if jseymour186 indeed used shift+returns ('soft' line breaks), this can trivially be adjusted.

Answer (score 0):

Would this be something for you?

```
\Q(3 parts)\E\r((?:.*$\R){3})
```

See [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/dJ7iK5/1). As @Jongware pointed out, it seems to be `\r` (lowercase) in Adobe InDesign.

Comment: this doesn't work when i try to use it in Adobe Indesign.

Comment: I don't recognize the \Q, \E or \R what do these characters do? I trying to figure out why Indesign doesn't recognized parts of this code.

Comment: @jseymour186: `\Q` and `\E` are valid GREP codes but are not explained in [Adobe's documentation on GREP](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/find-change.html#search_using_grep_expressions). They switch GREP code recognition 'off' and 'on', respectively, so the parentheses don't need escaping. `\R` does not work in InDesign; it needs to be `\r`. With that changed it works (it doesn't seem to need `(?m)` in InDesign). But this also selects the parenthesized part text at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-A` option in `grep`:

```
grep -A 3 -F '(3 parts)' file
NEW! Certificate in Office Operations (3 parts)
Office Operations
Cyber Security for Managers
Embracing Sustainability in the Workplace
```